# Ehcache in Spring MVC with parameters

Tags: spring-mvc, ehcache

Dear all,
                
                    I am using EhCache with Spring MVC 3. My server takes json from other server, I have added cache on it. It works fine when there is no parameters. Can I cache the json based on the parameters also.

Right now I am using method name as key for caching, can I include params also ??

Here is code 
`@Cacheable(value="products", key="#root.method.name")`

Thanks,
Dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, as described in Spring's [Cache abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html), the key will be computed from the parameters.
So try first with dropping the `key` attribute in your declaration and see what that does for you.
If you need to tweak the key computation, have a look at the documentation.

Comment: OK Thanks for your reply. Let me try this out.

Comment: Its working. Thanks a lot. One more thing wanted to check, what are the limitations of using EhCache with Spring. I have some big amount of data that comes after hitting the url. What happens if cache limit expired.

Comment: Not sure what your question is exactly. Expiry has a specific meaning in caching world - it indicates that an entry should no longer be returned as it is no longer considered valid. And so written next to "cache limit" it makes little sense. Are you concerned with not having enough memory? or something else?

Comment: No prob. Its already implemented now and working fine. I am getting one more issue, I have created two cache names but only one cache is working. What may be the possible reasons.